# JSON with single quote (') value not able to store in hidden input filed

Tags: php, html, json, yii2

I have this JSON data:

```
{"2018":{"id":18,"pa_id":27,"year":2018,"start_date":"2018-01-01 00:00:00","end_date":"2018-10-31 00:00:00","value":"6000","status_id":0,"is_duplicated":0,"state":0,"json_educational_expenses":"{\"current\":1,\"rowCount\":4,\"total\":4,\"rows\":[{\"account_number\":\"6013\",\"account_name\":\"Achat Mati\\u00e8re d'oeuvre\",\"amount\":\"15000.00\"},{\"account_number\":\"6067 \",\"account_name\":\"Fournitures et mat\\u00e9riel enseignement\",\"amount\":\"3000.00\"},{\"account_number\":\"6118 ss traitance\",\"account_name\":\"Sous-Traitance\",\"amount\":\"10000.00\"},{\"account_number\":\"625 d\\u00e9placements\",\"account_name\":\"Frais de d\\u00e9placements\",\"amount\":\"4000.00\"}],\"totalCost\":\"32000.00\"}","json_hr_cost":"{\"current\":1,\"rowCount\":3,\"total\":3,\"rows\":[{\"hr_id\":\"11\",\"hr_name\":\"MARTIN Bernard\",\"hr_function\":\"Education\",\"hr_function_id\":\"1\",\"hr_hour_type\":\"FACE\",\"hr_no_of_hours\":\"250\",\"hr_amount\":\"17500.00\"},{\"hr_id\":\"19\",\"hr_name\":\"PINOT Jo\\u00ebl\",\"hr_function\":\"Education\",\"hr_function_id\":\"1\",\"hr_hour_type\":\"FACE\",\"hr_no_of_hours\":\"350\",\"hr_amount\":\"11200.00\"},{\"hr_id\":\"15\",\"hr_name\":\"PEREZ Christelle\",\"hr_function\":\"Administration\",\"hr_function_id\":\"2\",\"hr_hour_type\":\"\",\"hr_no_of_hours\":\"300\",\"hr_amount\":\"8400.00\"}],\"totalCost\":\"37100.00\"}","json_thr_cost":"{\"current\":1,\"rowCount\":1,\"total\":1,\"rows\":[{\"temp_hr_id\":\"10\",\"temp_hr_name\":\"RICOT L\\u00e9a\",\"temp_hr_function\":\"Administration\",\"temp_hr_function_id\":\"2\",\"temp_hr_hour_type\":\"\",\"temp_hr_no_of_hours\":\"100\",\"temp_hr_amount\":961,\"hr_status_id\":\"2\",\"start_date\":\"2018-01-01 00:00:00\",\"end_date\":\"2018-10-31 00:00:00\",\"temp_hr_status\":\"Non Holder\",\"temp_hr_sum_of_taxes\":\"46.58% <\\\/span><\\\/a>\",\"temp_hr_sum_of_tax_amount\":\"447.63\",\"temp_hr_total_amount\":\"1408.63\"}],\"totalCost\":\"1408.63\"}","json_indirect_cost_distribution":"{\"current\":1,\"rowCount\":3,\"total\":3,\"rows\":[{\"re_id\":\"186\",\"account_number\":\"6581\",\"account_name\":\"Management Department Cost\",\"amount\":\"91150.00\",\"distributed_amount\":\"1470.56\"},{\"re_id\":\"177\",\"account_number\":\"613 Location\",\"account_name\":\"Location\",\"amount\":\"49365.48\",\"distributed_amount\":\"796.43\"},{\"re_id\":\"180\",\"account_number\":\"6801 dot amort\",\"account_name\":\"Dotation aux amortissements\",\"amount\":\"88857.87\",\"distributed_amount\":\"1433.58\"}],\"totalCost\":\"3700.57\"}","json_distributed_hr_ic":"{\"current\":1,\"rowCount\":0,\"total\":0,\"rows\":[],\"totalCost\":\"0.00\"}","json_distributed_thr_ic":"{\"current\":1,\"rowCount\":0,\"total\":0,\"rows\":[],\"totalCost\":\"0.00\"}","json_education_revenue":"{\"current\":1,\"rowCount\":2,\"total\":2,\"rows\":[{\"id\":\"158\",\"account_number\":\"70665 Cont entrepris\",\"account_name\":\"Contributions entreprises et organismes professionnels\",\"information\":\"\",\"trainee_number\":\"500\",\"hour_number\":\"4\",\"amount_per_hour\":\"20\",\"total\":\"40000.00\"},{\"id\":\"163\",\"account_number\":\"7442 Cons R\\u00e9gional\",\"account_name\":\"Conseil R\\u00e9gional\",\"information\":\"\",\"trainee_number\":\"8\",\"hour_number\":\"500\",\"amount_per_hour\":\"10\",\"total\":\"40000.00\"}],\"totalCost\":\"80000.00\"}"}}

<input id="cy_data" type="hidden" name="cy_data" value='<?= $cyData ?>' />
```

This JSON return from database and I store in hidden field but due to single quote it break the HTML.

Comment: Did you tray changing `value='` to `value="`? Use double quotes on it, not single?

Comment: Although it's probably best to escape your data

Comment: Yes, but not working

Comment: this is our uf8 format table can store anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`Html::encode()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml#encode()-detail) for encoding attributes (or any untrusted data):

```
<input id="cy_data" type="hidden" name="cy_data" value="<?= Html::encode($cyData) ?>" />
```

Or use [`Html::hiddenInput()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml#hiddenInput()-detail) - it will encode attributes for you:

```
<?= Html::hiddenInput('cy_data', $cyData, ['id' => 'cy_data']) ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to use **urlencode** to encode Json and allow store in hidden input without break html code.

`<input id="cy_data" type="hidden" name="cy_data" value='<?= urlencode($cyData) ?>' />`

> Documentation: [PHP: Urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Later in Controller, you can use **urldecode** method to retrieve data.

```
echo urldecode($foo);
```

> Documentation: [PHP: Urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

If you need manipulate data in hidden input with JS, you can use **decodeURIComponent**:

> Simple Example: [Javascript decodeUriComponent](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp)